# Unaccessible `__init__`

Tags: python

```
class MetaA(type):
  def __new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict):
    print('meta __new__ called')
    return super().__new__(self, clsname, bases, clsdict)

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print('meta __call__ called')
```

```
class A(metaclass=MetaA):
  def __init__(self, x):
    print('__init__ called')
    self.x = x
```

```
meta __new__ called
```

```
a = A(['1'])
```

```
meta __call__ called
```

```
type(a)
```

```
NoneType
```

It appears that specifying a `__call__` in the metaclass, blocks the `__init__` of the main class.
How do I access the `__init__` of the main class?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: In your case, `A(['1'])` is going to call your `__call__` function, which returns `None`.  It isn't going to create an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Meta.__call__` method doesn't return anything, which is the same as returning `None`. That's why `a` is `None` at the end of your code.

The default behavior of `type.__call__` (which you're overriding) is to create an instance and return it. If you still want that to happen, you need to call (and return the result of) `super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)`, similar to what you do in `Meta.__new__`.

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  print('meta __call__ called')
  return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I suppose you could instead reimplement the behavior of `type.__call__` (e.g. by calling the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of the class yourself), but unless you want to change some part of the default behavior, calling `type.__call__` to do it via `super()` is easier.

It's unrelated to your issue, but the first argument name you're using in your metaclass methods may lead you astray at some point. The `__new__` method is called as if it was a classmethod, with the metaclass as its first argument. The `__call__` method on the other hand is a normal method, being called on an instance of the metaclass, which is a class. I'd use `meta` (or maybe `mcls`) and `cls` as the argument names, respectively, to avoid confusion. I reserve `self` for regular classes, to refer to their own instances.

I guess if you wanted to reimplement `type.__call__`, you could use `self` to name the instance after you've created it:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
  print('meta __call__ called')

  self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) # create the instance with __new__

  if isinstance(self, cls):                # if __new__ didn't do something strange
    self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)         # call __init__ on the instance

  return self                              # then return it to the caller
```

Comment: what is the substitute for `super()` in `__call__`, `type.__call__(*args, *kwargs)` gives me `TypeError: descriptor '__call__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'list'`.

Comment: I had to provide the class as the first argument, then it works, `type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: also, do you know the implementation of manual `type.__new__(...)` and `type.__init__(...)` also, in case I do not want to call them, just like you told the manual implementation of `type.__call__(,,,)`

Comment: If you call `type.__call__` by name, rather than using `super()` to find the base class, then yes, you need to pass the first argument yourself, since you're invoking an unbound method. There's no way that I know of to reimplement `type.__new__`, it's too fundamental and too interconnected to the interpreter's internals. Trying to call `object.___new__(type)` (which would be a necessary first step) doesn't work, with the message `TypeError: object.__new__(type) is not safe, use type.__new__()`.